# Convex optimization with some cubic and quartic constraint?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am an engineer who is currently working with some network optimization problem. In my work, I encounter a strange optimization problem that seems to be convex but it has some cubic and quartic constraint. The problem look like this

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\mathop {\min }\limits_{x,y,z,t,y} }&{x + y + z + t + y}\\
{}&{{a_1}{x^3} + {a_2}{y^3} + {a_3}{z^3} - t \le 0}\\
{}&{{b_1}{x^4} + {b_2}{y^4} + {b_3}{z^4} - y \le 0}\\
{}&{x + y + z + t + y \ge 1}\\
{}&{...{\rm{and}}\,{\rm{some}}\,{\rm{linear}}\,{\rm{constraints}}}
\end{array}$

Here all of $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ and $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$ are just some positive number. The decision variable $x,y,z,t,y$ are non negative.

What should I do to deal with this type of problem ?.

Edit:

In some situations, the objective function is not linear but may be a sum of quadratic and cubic terms ${x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2} + {t^3} + {y^3}$

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a model to be convex, both the objective function and the feasible region must be convex. The objective function $x + 2y + z + t$ is convex because it is linear, so we can get that out of the way. For a constraint to be convex, its eigenvalues for the hessian must be positive. In other words, there are two definitions we need to use:

- A matrix is called positive semi-definite if it is symmetric and all its eigenvalues are non-negative.
- If the Hessian matrix is positive semi-definite at all points in a set, then the function is convex in that set.

Now let us look at each constraint individually,

The constraint $x + 2y + z + t \ge 1$ is linear, so that is done. For $a_1x^3+a_2y^3+a_3z^3−t\le0$, the Hessian is:

\begin{bmatrix}
6a_1x & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 6a_2y & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 6a_3z & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}

In which the eigenvalues (the diagonals) are non-negative since $x,y,z\ge0$ and $a_1,a_2,a_3>0$, therefore this is convex. Likewise, for constraint $b_1x^4+b_2y^4+b_3z^4−y$, the Hessian is:

\begin{bmatrix}
12b_1x^2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 12b_2y^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 12b_3z^2
\end{bmatrix}

In which the eigenvalues (the diagonals) are non-negative since $x,y,z\ge0$ and $b_1,b_2,b_3>0$, therefore this is convex.

Therefore, this model is convex with the original problem for the particular region space. For the additional objective function, the Hessian of that is,

\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 6y+2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 6t
\end{bmatrix}

The same logic applies, and it is therefore convex.

Comment: Thank you ! so much, I also suspect that it is convex. However one big problem is that current solver can work very well for quadratic convex problem. In this case, although it is convex but the constraint is cubic and quartic. Does this pose a problem ?

Comment: What kind of silver are you using? I'd imagine Ampl's public solvers could handle it well

Comment: also, if this answered your question, be sure to click the check under the vote button!

Comment: I mean in practice Convex quadratic solver can solve these kind of problem very fast. Is there any way to reduce my problem to quadratic form or something ?

Comment: If you're willing to solve for gradients or find it easier to solve gradients in the environment you are using, you could instead try to solve the KKT conditions of the problem, [this](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F16/scribes/kkt-scribed.pdf)  and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions). Otherwise, I don't immediately see a good way to reduce the problem - you may wanna post it as another question for someone else who might be able to see it/has more current time